# Create a 2010 workflow in Visual Studio 2012 for SharePoint hosted app

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-hosted-app, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to create workflow 2010 for SharePoint hosted app 2013 in visual studio 2012. If yes then how we can achieve this. Suggest some help

Comment: have you got the Answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can easily create Workflow in SharePoint Add-ins using Visual Studio.

You can go through the following link which contains best example of SharePoint Workflow for SharePoint Add-ins.

[Add a workflow to a SharePoint-hosted SharePoint Add-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt148590.aspx)

Let me know your thoughts about this.

Comment: But I want to add 2010's workflow